# How Can I give date dynamically using mysql date_format?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I am working on requirement of generating reports of for every 7, 15, 30, 50, 75 or 100 days respectively where user selects his choice by a select dropdown. First I wrote query to generate report for 7 days which was worked fine. But I am not sure how to make that selection dynamic based on user selection.

My query for 7 days report is below:

```
SELECT table1.order_id FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.order_id = table2.order_id  WHERE table1.assigned_user_id=:assigned_user_id AND DATE(table2.track_date) >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND table2.order_status=2 GROUP BY table1.order_id
```

My select dropdown is:

```
<select name="supply_analysis" id="supply_analysis" class="supply_analysis">
            <option value="7" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='7')?'selected':''?>>7 days</option>
            <option value="15" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='15')?'selected':''?> >15 days</option>
            <option value="30" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='30')?'selected':''?> >30 days</option>
            <option value="50" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='50')?'selected':''?> >50 days</option>
            <option value="75" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='75')?'selected':''?> >75 days</option>
            <option value="100" <?php echo (isset($_GET['analysis']) && $_GET['analysis']=='100')?'selected':''?> >100 days</option>
 </select>
```

My query to generate report based on user choice is:

```
"SELECT table1.order_id FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.order_id = table2.order_id  WHERE table1.assigned_user_id=:assigned_user_id AND DATE(table2.track_date) >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ".$_GET['analysis']." DAY) AND table2.order_status=2 GROUP BY table1.order_id"
```

Presently, The query seems to be working but I am not sure if it is working fine or not. Please any suggestions/help? Thanks.

Comment: do you use php at the backend ?

Comment: Yes I use php as a backend, @Ali

Answer (score 0):

take look at this :

```
$values = [7 , 15 , 30 , 50 , 75 , 100];

if(in_array($values , $supply_analysis)) //use this to prevent SQL injection 
{
  $SQL = "SELECT table1.order_id 
          FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.order_id = table2.order_id  
          WHERE table1.assigned_user_id=:assigned_user_id AND DATE(table2.track_date) >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL {$supply_analysis} DAY) AND table2.order_status=2 GROUP BY table1.order_id";

  //do your database query here

}
```

`$supply_analysis` is the value that submitted from your form

Comment: Thanks, I will try this but it seems to work fine. I will get back to you again.